# Looking up index in a MongoDB array

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, query-optimization, pymongo

Our data provider supplies the data in a weird format. The arrays `date` and `value` are corresponding and guaranteed to have the same length. For whatever reason, they even decide to mix up int and string values in `date`.

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "A000005933",
    "date": [905270400000, 918748800000, 937843200000, 965923200000, 983289600000, 984931200000, 1152806400000, "1171987200000", "1225382400000", "1229616000000", "1286208000000", "1455552000000"],
    "value": ["0.25", "0.15", "0", "0.25", "0.15", "0", "0.25", "0.5", "0.3", "0.1", "0.1", "-0.1"],
    "version": 1614837436798
  },
  {
    "_id": "A000005934",
    "date": [915120000000, 923587200000, 941731200000, 949593600000, 953222400000, 956851200000, 962121600000, 967737600000, 970761600000, 989510400000, 999187200000, 1000742400000, 1005235200000, 1039104000000, 1046966400000, 1054828800000, 1133798400000, 1141747200000, 1150300800000, 1155052800000, 1160496000000, 1165939200000, 1173801600000, 1181664000000, 1215532800000, 1224000000000, 1226419200000, 1228838400000, 1232467200000, 1236700800000, 1239120000000, 1242144000000, 1302624000000, 1310486400000, 1320768000000, 1323792000000, 1341936000000, 1367942400000, 1384272000000, 1402416000000, 1410278400000, 1458057600000],
    "value": ["3", "2.5", "3", "3.25", "3.5", "3.78", "4.25", "4.5", "4.78", "4.5", "4.25", "3.75", "3.25", "2.78", "2.5", "2", "2.25", "2.5", "2.75", "3", "3.25", "3.5", "3.75", "4", "4.25", "3.75", "3.25", "2.5", "2", "1.5", "1.25", "1", "1.25", "1.5", "1.25", "1", "0.75", "0.5", "0.25", "0.15", "0.05", "0"],
    "version": 1614837436548
  },
  ......
]
```

Our typical use case is to look up `value` based on `_id` and `date`, so I had to do something like this.

```py
def get_value_from_mongo(id_: str, date: datetime.date) -> float:
    result = db.indicators.find_one({"_id": _id}, {"value": 1, "date": 1})
    date_list = list(map(str, result["date"]))
    price_list = list(map(str, result["value"]))

    dt = date.strftime("%s000")
    price = float(price_list[date_list.index(dt)])

    return price
```

This is hopelessly inefficient because the whole array is scanned each time I want to retrieve a single value. Maybe I could do a binary search, but `date` is not guaranteed to be sorted and I don't want to rely on that behavior.

Are there any MongoDB operators I can use to speed up the query?

Comment: Have you considered ingesting the data differently so you can index and query it in a more efficient way?

Comment: @Joe Kind of, but doing ETL/ELT sounds like a lot of work and I'm not sure I can do it right. I mean, there is a lot of data and I need to do regular merging and monitoring. Sounds pretty complicated to me :/

Comment: as the saying goes, you pay for things on the front end or the backend, if you chose to pay here on the backend, I suppose that's what it is.  You may consider turning this query into an aggregation framework job so your mongo cluster can perform it rather than your business app.

Comment: I don't understand what should be returned. The priceS which match (date, id) ? Or are you making assumption array will never contain dupes ?

Comment: @grodzi The `date` array will never contain duplicates, and each element in `date` corresponds to the element at the same index in `value`. More concretely, the price (i.e. value) for id `A000005933` on date `923587200000` is `0.15` in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

1. A first possibility is to focus on the lookup: create an index on dates array

Which comes at the sake of a slower write.

In below execution plan you can see the index is used (you should benchmark if it brings *that* of an improvement)

```
> db.indicators.explain().find({dates: '1.1'})
{
  "queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "dummy.indicators",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
      "dates" : {
        "$eq" : "1.1"
      }
    },
    "queryHash" : "4204704C",
    "planCacheKey" : "1DBFE945",
    "winningPlan" : {
      "stage" : "FETCH",
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",// <------
        "keyPattern" : {
          "dates" : 1
        },
        "indexName" : "dates_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "multiKeyPaths" : {
          "dates" : [
            "dates"
          ]
        },
        "isUnique" : false,
        "isSparse" : false,
        "isPartial" : false,
        "indexVersion" : 2,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "indexBounds" : {
          "dates" : [
            "[\"1.1\", \"1.1\"]"
```

2. A second possibility is to focus on retrieving the minimal data possible

With hint that bottleneck is not the date lookup but the data transfer

Thus this does not improve the lookup (given you "iterate" your array on db side instead of application code side).

You can make it with the use of

- the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)
- the projection as second argument in find with mongo >= 4.4

```
db.indicators.remove({})
db.indicators.insert([{_id: '0', dates: [1, '1.1', 2], prices: [1,2,3]}])
fetch = date => {
  print(date)
  res = db.indicators.find(
    {
      dates: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $in: [Number(date), String(date)]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      'prices.$': 1 // <<--------
    }
  ).toArray()
  printjson(res)
}
fetch(2) // [ { "_id" : "0", "prices" : [ 3 ] } ]
fetch('1.1') // [ { "_id" : "0", "prices" : [ 2 ] } ]
```

---

Obviously you can compose 1 and 2, but I would have a try with just 2 to avoid creating an index